# New to Git and GitHub, am I doing it wrong?

Tags: github, msysgit

I make a change to one existing file test.cs

1. git add .
2. git commit -m "my change to test.cs"
3. git pull origin master
4. > it pulls down SomeOtherFile.cs (changed by someone else, not new)
5. > I check the build... )
6. git push

When I go to github, there are two commits under my push, one for 'test.cs', and one for SomeOtherFile.cs

Is this expected behavior?

Thanks..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So what you are running into here is the difference between a Merge and a Rebase.  When you did the:

```
git pull origin master
```

You created a merge commit which merged the changes in from master.  That merge commit was empty, but it was created.  This behavior from merge is expected, but in my opinion undesirable.  The commit was created to hold the differences between the two branches (Your local and Origin Master), and is created regardless of the existence of any differences.  If you had instead issued

```
git pull --rebase origin master
```

You would have done a rebase.  A rebase looks for the last commit your local and Origin Master have in common, sets aside into temporary storage your changes since that commit, then layers on the changes from Origin Master (the SomeOtherFile.cs commit from NotYou), and finally replays your changes on top of that new updated line.  This replaying is done commit by commit, so if you're 10 commits ahead it will happen 10 times.

If there are no conflicts, then this all happens instantly and without intervention.  If there is a conflict, then you will be stopped in the middle, asked to correct the problem, and then you issue a

```
git rebase --continue
```

to have the process move on.  What happens here is that conflicts are handled by redefining your original commit, rather than by adding a merge commit.  But it keeps the file histories clean, which merge does not as you have seen.

Answer (score 2):

When you do `git add .`, you will add changes to *any* files in your working directory to the index. If you only want to create a commit for `test.cs`, do instead:

```
git add test.cs
```

Comment: Right, and I only touched one file. The add . was done before my commit and before the pull. So the only file that changed at that point was test.cs.

Comment: So who changed `SomeOtherFile.cs`?

Comment: hm... edited this line in the original post:  4. > it pulls down SomeOtherFile.cs (changed by someone else, not new). Does that make more sense?

Comment: Okay, it sounds like the commit for `SomeOtherFile.cs` was *already* on Github, and by doing a `git pull origin master` you merged what was on Github into your local repository. I think you may be misreading what Github is telling you, because I'm not quite sure what you mean by "two commits under my push". A "push" is not something that contains a list of new commits. When you push, Git ensures that the remote has *all* the commits from your current head back to the beginning of (repository) time.

Comment: The actual "merge" is what I have a problem with. SomeOtherFile.cs was already on my box. Some other user just changed the file. I had not touched SomeOtherFile.cs since my last pull. Why is this a merge? Why does it not just replace the file on my system? This seems completely wrong.

Comment: It's a "merge" because you're bringing two different histories together into one. One history is the other dev changing `SomeOtherFile.cs`, and the other history is you changing `test.cs`. Git calls this a merge because the changes aren't already linear. In this case it is a *trivial* merge because you and the other dev changed different files with no overlap. Git should, as you say, replace the `SomeOtherFile.cs` on your system with the new one as changed by the other dev.

Comment: so... not sure af I am still confused, or if what I described it what git and github should be doing. Git does/is as I said, replacing SomeOtherFile.cs on my system. Still, why does the 'trivial' checkin I make duplicate his changes and put my name on them, as if I made them to the file itself. Is that part supposed to happen?

Comment: No, Git doesn't normally duplicate changes and change the commit author name. Unless perhaps you used the "rebase" functionality somewhere along the way and didn't mention it. Since Git is so flexible, there are many things that *could* have happened and it's hard for me to guess at this point. I recommend a good book such as [Pro Git](http://progit.org) (which is written by one of the GitHub guys).

Comment: ok.. so *something* is wrong here.. and this should not be happening. Thank you. I have asked so many people, and they keep telling me "yeah, it works that way". I don't think a rebase hs been performed. Even so.. would it not affect the next change, instead of every change from then on? Do you really need to buy a book to get the basics? What could be wrong in those simple steps.

Comment: Pro Git is free, you don't need to buy it. You can read the entire book online if you want. See the web site.